# Content in the middle (grid)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I like to put `career-text` in the middle which is expended by `col-md-8` but how to put empty space/grid (col-md-2) on the left and on the right?

```
<div class="career-text col-md-8"> Text Text Text </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The official doc** : http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-offsetting

**Use** `offset` Class

**Ex** :

```
<div class="career-text col-md-offset-2 col-md-8"> Text Text Text </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That has worked for me ...

```
<div class="col-md-2"></div>
<div class="col-md-8" style="text-align:center;">dsfsdfsdf</div>
<div class="col-md-2"></div>
```

(the `style="text-align:center"` just centers the text in the div...)